# Issue with shell if statement

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script as follows (taken from some lecture slides):

```
#/bin/sh
echo -e "enter a number:\c"
read number
if [$number -ne 2]
  then
     echo "Number is not equals to 2"
fi
```

And I'm getting a syntax error where `fi` is. Any idea what the problem is?

Also, what does the `extra` term in `echo -e "enter a number:\c"` means (asides from the simple fact that it asks for a number)?

<strike>**EDIT**: now I did</strike>

```
#/bin/sh
echo -e "enter a number:\c"
read number
if [ "$number" -ne 2 ]
then
   echo "Number is not equals to 2"
fi
```

And I'm still getting the error...

Same goes for

```
#/bin/sh
read -p "enter a number: " number
if [ "$number" -ne 2 ]
then
   echo "Number is not equals to 2"
fi
```

**SOLVED**: I've made a copying error there. Thanks for the input by the way, guys.

Comment: Your revised script (immediately following "EDIT: now I did) works correctly; when I run it and enter `2` it doesn't print the message.

Comment: Ok, I think I realised my little mistake and fixed it.

Comment: It works for me. Is the script in your question *exactly* the same as what you're running? Did you copy-and-paste it into your question?

Comment: The script was much longer and this was just a snippet. I made a small copying mistake, which caused the problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: Step 3 in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) is "Test your example. Make sure it runs and still shows the problem. *Do not brush this off*." :P

Comment: @thatotherguy Sorry, newbie here :/ and I was kind of in a rush... You know, we have a tendency to rush things. But I did test the code and it was actually just a minor copying code in another part of the file... My bad.

Comment: Maybe you have a look at 'help read' and the -p Prompt parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is this if condition:

```
if [$number -ne 2]
```

You need to put space after `[` and before `]` so use:

```
if [ "$number" -ne 2 ]
```

Your script can be rewritten as:

```
#/bin/sh
read -p "enter a number: " number
if [ "$number" -ne 2 ]
then
   echo "Number is not equals to 2"
fi
```

However if bash is available then better to switch to bash instead of old bourne shell.

Comment: ok replace `#/bin/sh` by `#/bin/bash` and run it using `bash -ex script.sh`

Comment: @user3511965: A `$` doesn't tell you what shell you're running. If you're running bash, then `echo $BASH_VERSION` will show its version number. But the shell you're running interactively is not related to the shell used to run your script. The suggestion is to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in your script -- though in this case it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @anubhava: What's the advantage of bash over sh *for this script*?

Comment: Okay, thanks! It's working now, just a little error of mines. What about the -e tag and \c, what are those?

Comment: @KeithThompson No real advantage, I wrote answer using `/bin/sh` itself but OP still ran into issues so I suggested bash just for a testing since I am not sure why is `/bin/sh` not working for OP.